# Asymptotic complexity of string indexing in .NET

Tags: .net, string, asymptotic-complexity

Since .NET stores strings in UTF-16 and considering the fact that it's variable length encoding (single code unit can take 2 or 4 bytes).

Does it mean that string indexing (`s[n]`) takes O(n)?

Comment: No, indexing a string produces a System.Char, not a type that can store a codepoint from the upper planes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.Net strings do not treat non-BMP code units as single characters; string APIs will return surrogate pairs as two characters.

Therefore, as far as `string` is concerned, UTF-16 is not a variable-length encoding.

If you want to see UTF-32 code units, call [`Char.GetNumericValue()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs,4d29d822ae086684), which is O(n).

Comment: Is it fair to say that .NET strings are UCS-2 and not UTF-16?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: Yes

Comment: This could be worded better. .NET _does_ fully support UTF-16 surrogate pairs in many of the places where doing so is required (collation, rendering, etc.). It is `String` specifically that doesn't support it.

Comment: @CoryNelson: Clarified.